# How do I make a Reusable components package for React native/expo apps using expo packages

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I tried to look it up but quickly got confused|

I have a package for reusable mobile components that's in a monorepo alongside multiple expo apps. Most of the components in this package are your average styled views and stuff, and all of the apps import the packages as

`import ComponentName from "@my-package/Component"`

It works well with all the base react native components, but now I need to specifically use an expo package (expo-icons) and I was wondering

1.- Aren't these packages tightly coupled to your expo version? They come prepackaged on expo init and you don't explicitly install anything.

2.- Is there any way to use them without explicitly installing anything in node modules? like `Rely on whatever version of expo/vector-icons is installed in the app importing this package instead of whatever @my-package has installed`

3.- If I relied in https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons which should work, how is the link step handled in the installing apps? Like App A imports an icon component from my package, `do I need to explicitly go to my package and copy the fonts? Do I need to install https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons in app A?`

I can tell these are likely questions that deal a lot more with how npm works but I have not gone too deep into it so I apologize if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `peerDependencies` for such packages.

See https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob#how-do-i-add-a-react-native-library-containing-native-code-as-a-dependency-in-my-library

Re: `@expo/vector-icons`, you can use `react-native-vector-icons` in your code and it'll work in both Expo and non-Expo apps since expo maps it to `@expo/vector-icons` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, we are also actually using builder-bob but I did not consider checking out their repository for answers.
So basically add react-native-vector-icons as a peer dependency and as a dev dependency on `my-package` and that's it? Importing in app A from `my-package` should correctly have everything setup?
Setting it as Peer dependency will force me to install react-nativevector-icons in app A, but for example on expo that will explicitly use `expo/vector-icons` so I also need to install react-native-vector-icons?

Comment: P.S. Any reference/source link to `expo maps it to @expo/vector-icons automatically`?

Comment: You can check react-native-paper repository which uses react-native-vector-icons but also works with @expo/vector-icons seamlessly